# Countable Hilbert space direct sum of sets of complex numbers has a countable basis with cardinality $\infty$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $H:=\bigoplus_{n}^{\infty}H_{n}$, where $H_n=\mathbb{C}$ for all $n$. The inner product for $H$ is given by $\langle x,y\rangle=\underset{n=1}{\overset{\infty}{\sum}}\langle x_{n},y_{n}\rangle_{n}$.

I want to prove that $H$ has a basis with cardinality $\infty$ (I know it is countable because I have already proved that $H$ is separable: any subset of a separable metric space is separable (with the induced subspace metric), and $H$ is a subset of the separable metric space $\underset{n=1}{\overset{\infty}{\prod}}\mathbb{C}$, which is itself separable because the countable cartesian product of separable spaces is separable.)

I will assume that $\mathbb{C}$ is taken as a vector space over the field $\mathbb{C}$ - I believe this is standard. Thus, $\mathbb{C}$ has the basis $\{1\}$. Now, let 
$$
\mathcal{B}=\{(1,0,0,...),(0,1,0,...),...\}
$$
$\mathcal{B}$ is a countable set (with cardinality $\infty$): the map $\mathbb{N}\overset{f}{\rightarrow}\mathcal{B}$  with $f(n)=(0,...,0,\overset{n^{th}\mbox{ entry}}{\overbrace{1}},0,...)$ is clearly a bijection.

To show that it is a basis for $H$, it suffices to prove that $\mathcal{B}$ is an orthonormal set and the set of finite linear combinations of elements of $\mathcal{B}$ is dense in $H$.
Let $b_{i},b_{j}\in\mathcal{B}$, where $b_{i}=f(i)$ and $b_{j}=f(j)$. We have $$
\langle b_{i},b_{j}\rangle=\underset{n=1}{\overset{\infty}{\sum}}\langle b_{i,n},b_{j,n}\rangle_{n}
$$
But $b_{i,n}=\delta_{i,n}$, so 
$$
\langle b_{i},b_{j}\rangle=\underset{n=1}{\overset{\infty}{\sum}}\langle\delta_{i,n},\delta_{j,n}\rangle_{n}=\begin{cases}
0 & ,i\ne j\\
\langle1,1\rangle_{i} & ,i\ne j
\end{cases}
$$

The inner products $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_{n}$ are the usual inner product in $\mathbb{C}$. We get $\langle1,1\rangle_{i}=\vert1\vert^{2}=1$. Hence $\langle b_{i},b_{j}\rangle=\delta_{i,j}$, and thus $\mathcal{B}$ is an orthonormal set.

We still need to prove that the set $S$ of finite linear combinations of elements of $\mathcal{B}$ is dense in $H$.
Let $x\in H$. I want to prove that for any $\epsilon>0$
 we have $B_{\epsilon}(x)\cap S\ne\emptyset$. Thus, I want to find $z\in H$
  with 
$$z=\underset{i=1}{\overset{N}{\sum}}c_{i}b_{i}$$

(with the $c_{i}\in\mathbb{C}$ and $N$ some natural number) such that

$$\parallel z-x\parallel<\epsilon$$

*i.e.* 
$$\underset{n=1}{\overset{\infty}{\sum}}\parallel z_{n}-x_{n}\parallel_{n}^{2}<\epsilon^{2}$$

But $$\parallel z_{n}-x_{n}\parallel_{n}^{2}=\parallel\underset{i=1}{\overset{N}{\sum}}c_{i}b_{i,n}-x_{n}\parallel_{n}^{2}=$$

$$=\parallel\underset{i=1}{\overset{N}{\sum}}c_{i}\delta_{i,n}-x_{n}\parallel_{n}^{2}=\begin{cases}
\parallel c_{n}-x_{n}\parallel_{n}^{2} & ,\,n\le N\\
\parallel x_{n}\parallel_{n}^{2} & ,\,n>N
\end{cases}$$

Hence 
$$\underset{n=1}{\overset{\infty}{\sum}}\parallel z_{n}-x_{n}\parallel_{n}^{2}=\underset{n=1}{\overset{N}{\sum}}\parallel c_{n}-x_{n}\parallel_{n}^{2}+\underset{n=N+1}{\overset{\infty}{\sum}}\parallel x_{n}\parallel_{n}^{2}$$

But I am now failing to see how I can assign values to these $c_{i}$
  in order to make sure that this is smaller than $\epsilon^{2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x = (x_1,x_2,\dots) \in H$ then the sum $\sum_n |x_n|^2$ converges. The sum converges if and only if for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists an integer $N$ such that $\sum_{n \ge N} |x_n|^2 < \varepsilon^2$. So if you take

$$ z = \sum_{n = 1}^{N - 1} x_nb_n $$

then

$$ \lVert z - x \rVert^2 = \sum_{n = N}^\infty |x_n|^2 < \varepsilon^2. $$

Comment: "The sum converges if and only if for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists an integer $N$ such that $\sum_{n \ge N} |x_n|^2 < \varepsilon^2$."
Could you elaborate on that, please?

Comment: I just got it, thank you.